# Setting FQDN hostname and dot

Tags: linux, hostname, fqdn

I was wondering if I am editing a file such as `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/sysconfig/network` should I put a `.` at the end of the name. such as `test.example.com.`

Is there a difference? Would anything break either way.

Answer (score 6):

According to [`man hosts`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?hosts):

> Host  names  may  contain  only  alphanumeric characters, minus signs
>   ("-"), and periods (".").  **They must begin with an  alphabetic 
>   character  *and  end  with  an  alphanumeric  character*.**

Answer (score 2):

Entries in /etc/hosts are never expanded with a domain, it's a simple table lookup, and hence, trailing dots are meaningless and likely to cause issues.  Also as mentioned in another answer, the specification for /etc/hosts rules them out (for this reason).

Answer (score 2):

Trailing dot is not meaningless.
If you try to access a host with FQDN(which includes trailing dot), your application will lookup the name from DNS not /etc/hosts if the hostname in /etc/hosts does not have trailing dot.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen anyone use a trailing dot there, so you probably shouldn't.  Even though nothing might break right now, it's just tempting fate, as something might not expect it.